# undefined function when function is present but late

Tags: php

I have this file structure in my php project:

splitted.php (ERROR)

```
<?php
require_once "include1.php";
require_once "include2.php";
```

include1.php

```
<?php
a();
```

include2.php

```
<?php
function a(){ echo "success"; }
```

It will gives error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function a().
But if we combined them with the same exact sequence, it doesnt gives error.

combined.php (SUCCESS)

```
<?php
a();
function a(){ echo "success"; }
```

Why it gives error when we splitted the code but run without issue when we combine it? How to fix this error without altering the structure and the sequence of the file?

Comment: Remember with an include the code does not exists in the main script until the include has completed which seems very well demonstrated by your code

Comment: ___How to fix___ run `require_once "include2.php";` first

Comment: _If you declare class in include2.php and call that class in include1.php. It works without issue_ **Are you sure about that, it does not work on my system**

Comment: Oh and you `lytabu` are the OP, slightly odd refering to yourself in the third person. And if a solution whereby the order is not changed is not possible, it is just not possible